# Synchronize two functions

Tags: c++, synchronization

I am currently trying to sync two different funtions to fill a vector with numbers. One function fills the vector with even numbers, the other one with odd numbers. The numbers should be inserted in the correct order in the vector (that the result is: numbers [i] = i)

```
void incOdd(std::vector<uint8_t> *numbers, TestMutex *inEven, TestMutex *inOdd){

    for(uint8_t i = 1; i < 100;i++){
        if((i + 1) % 2 == 0){
            continue;
        }


        inOdd->lock();
        (*numbers).push_back(i);
        inOdd->unlock();

    }

}

void incEven(std::vector<uint8_t> *numbers, TestMutex *inEven, TestMutex *inOdd){

    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 100;i++){


        if(i % 2 != 0){
            continue;
        }


        inEven->lock();
        (*numbers).push_back(i);
        inEven->unlock();

    }
}
```

Just a Note: Test mutex is just a class that is a child of the mutex where only the lock and unlock function are defined. ( the lock function has a counter for the tests later)

Since it is a practice task, the parameters must not be changed and work only in parentheses. I Already tried to use condition_variables to let them wait for each other but it doesn't worked.
I have no other approaches and hope you have a solution for me

Update:

```
TEST_CASE("synchronize [thread]") {
    TestMutex inEven;
    TestMutex inOdd;
    inEven.lock();
    std::vector<uint8_t> numbers;

    std::thread even(incEven,&numbers,&inEven,&inOdd);
    std::thread odd(incOdd,&numbers,&inEven,&inOdd);

    odd.join();
    even.join();
    for(size_t i=0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
        REQUIRE(numbers[i] == (i+1));
    }
    REQUIRE(numbers.size() == 100);
    REQUIRE(inEven.c==51);
    REQUIRE(inOdd.c==50);
}
```

So this is the Test Case i have to solve for this question i am not allowd to change this.

Comment: Why do you pass both mutexes to both functions when only one is used in each?

Comment: Because thats my current problem ... i know for what i am using one of them but i dont know what to do with the other one ... thats part of the question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my code which is self explanatory:

```
#include "stdafx.h"    
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;


condition_variable cv;
bool odd = false;

typedef  mutex TestMutex;

void incOdd(std::vector<uint8_t> *numbers,TestMutex *inEven,TestMutex *inOdd) {

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(*inEven);
            cv.wait(lock, []() { return odd == false; });
            numbers->push_back(i);
            odd = true;
            cv.notify_one();
        }

    }

}

void incEven(std::vector<uint8_t> *numbers, TestMutex *inEven, TestMutex *inOdd) {

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 100; i++) {


        if (i % 2 != 0) {

            unique_lock<mutex> lock(*inEven);
            cv.wait(lock, []() { return odd == true; });
            numbers->push_back(i);
            odd = false;
            cv.notify_one();
        }

    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<uint8_t> vec;
    TestMutex mu;
    TestMutex rmu; // redundant
    thread thread1([&]() { incEven(&vec,&mu,&rmu); });
    thread thread2([&]() { incOdd(&vec,&mu,&rmu); });

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();

    for (auto e : vec)
        cout << int(e) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your work ... thats probably a way to solve my problem but i am not allowed to change the signature of the functions so the input parameters have to be the same like in my question. I added the Test case i have to solve for this so you see what my purpose is

Comment: @Retrogott: edited to match your function signature. But one mutex is still redundant IMHO.